# sequalize создаёт не верный запрос, когда в модель прописываешь defaultValue

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, express, sequelize.js

Делаю модель таблицы в sequlize (sql server):

```
function model(sequelize) {
    const attributes = {
        firstName: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
        lastName: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
        username: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
        hash: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
        role: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, defaultValue: 'user' }
    }
```

при запуске сервера выдаёт ошибку мол RequestError: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DEFAULT'. Запрос в которым он пытается создать поле role :

```
ALTER TABLE [Users] ALTER COLUMN [role] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT N'user';
```

откуда берётся буква N после DEFAULT ни как не пойму.

Comment: `N` - это префикс юникодных литералов. Обратите внимание на тип: **N**VARCHAR.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6791675/5045688

Comment: @Alexander Petrov
тогда не совсем понял что делать с seqalize? что бы работало? в Model synchronization использовать force: true но тогда теряешь все данные при каждой синхронизации. Или всегда синхронить с помощью CLI?

Comment: Вряд ли я смогу подсказать. При изменении колонки нельзя использовать такой синтаксис. Получается, что ошибка в генераторе sql.